Use comint with non-interactive CLI tools
Is it possible to run a CLI tool (via sql-* comint-based mode) that checks isatty() and immediately exits because the stdin is empty?
Maybe it is possible to force comint (or SQL mode) to run the tool each time I try to send something to it (a paragraph, a buffer, etc)?

Might something like this help? https://superuser.com/questions/1430872/how-to-simulate-a-shell-without-tty
